# Why does the iOS simulator require i386 and x86_64 symbols even though I'm on an x86_64 system only?

Tags: ios-simulator, x86-64, i386

I'm trying to get an app running on the simulator that has had some problems doing so before.  We don't have libjpeg.a built for `i386`, but it does have `x86_64`.  This is the only dependency left, but I'm wondering why I actually need `i386` symbols, if I'm running on an `x86_64` mac.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The iOS simulator can run your app in 32 and 64-bit modes.  This allows you to work out a lot of 64-bit issues and make sure it is ready for both armv7 and arm64.  To do this, it compiles your app for i386 and x86_64 and requires the libraries for both architectures.

Comment: Thanks yes I figured this out just after posting.  I was figuring that I'd at least be able to deploy to a 64 bit virtual target without 32 bit symbols and that perhaps Xcode would only attempt to link 32 bit when deploying to a 32 bit virtual target.  I got around it in the meantime by just removing arm7 from the build settings.  Nonetheless, you are correct and deserve the right answer.

Answer (score 28):

iOS apps need to run on many different architectures:

```
arm7: Used in the oldest iOS 7-supporting devices
arm7s: As used in iPhone 5 and 5C
arm64: For the 64-bit ARM processor in iPhone 5S
i386: For the 32-bit simulator
x86_64: Used in 64-bit simulator
```

Comment: I'm aware of the different architectures.  However my question was more about the particular case of why builds for both architecture were necessary simply for a simulator build.  There appear to be a multitude of reasons why (e.g. your app is universal for iPad and iPhone, but Xcode SDK actually uses older 32 bit architecture to emulate older environments as they haven't been updated to 64 bit).

Answer (score 9):

While these days I have tried to run Fastlane to get iOS screen capture, I found the same situation:Because there is `.a` library contains only `x86_64` architecture,but without `i386` architecture,and then I got this error:

```
Undefined symbol(s) for architecture i386
```

This is running on `iPhone 8` simulator with `iOS 11.4`.

But you can force the simulator to run on only `64-bit` or only `32-bit` as follows:

```
Project -> Architectures -> set the value as:$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) or $(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT)
```

Answer (score 8):

actually **i386** architecture is for iPhone simulator where as **x86_64** architecture is for iPad simulators, both are 32 and 64bit compatible.

Comment: Can you provide source please?

Comment: I don't think so this is correct. There are iPhone simulators with 64 bit compatible versions.