# After installing Firebase with CocoaPod, I can no longer build

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cordova, cocoapods

I'm trying to build Javascript source code as an iOS app using Cordova.

I have introduced firebase with CocoaPods, and I am very troubled because I can not build.

**this is wannings**

```
Ignoring file /Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProductName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
```

**This is Error**

[image]

*Undefined symbols* occur in large numbers

**This is my Cocoapod profile.**

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'product_name' do
  use_frameworks!
  project 'product_name.xcodeproj'
    use_frameworks!
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
   pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 0.2'
   # ID Instance
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
   # config
   pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
   # Pods for PodTest
   pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
   pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
   # Bluetooth
   pod 'RxBluetoothKit'
   # debug
   pod 'SimulatorStatusMagic', :configurations => ['Debug']
   # design pattern
   pod 'Swinject'
   # zip
   pod 'Zip'
   # Protect UI
   pod 'iOSDFULibrary'
   pod 'libb2s'
end

target 'shareExtension' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
   pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 0.2'
   # ID Instance
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
   # config
   pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
   # Pods for PodTest
   pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
   pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
   # Bluetooth
   pod 'RxBluetoothKit'
   # debug
   pod 'SimulatorStatusMagic', :configurations => ['Debug']
   # design pattern
   pod 'Swinject'
   # zip
   pod 'Zip'
   # Protect UI
   pod 'iOSDFULibrary'
   pod 'libb2s'
 end
```

**My Enviroment**:

XCode Version 11.5
CocoaPods Version 1.9.3

**What I have done so far.**

STEP 1 : Solved CocoaPods Warnnings.

STEP 2 : Error Id: library Not Found XXXX
→ I installed the Not Found framework with CocoaPod(And decided to install a lot)

STEP3 : Modify Library Search Paths

STEP4 : Set Build Active Architecture Only explicitly to No

If anyone has experienced a similar error, I would like some advice on the current error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I found an explanation in the condition of the build using the simulator.

**Premise:**
[Why does the iOS simulator require i386 and x86_64 symbols even though I'm on an x86_64 system only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033635/why-does-the-ios-simulator-require-i386-and-x86-64-symbols-even-though-im-on-an)

**Implementation example:**
[Could not find module for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957632/could-not-find-module-for-target-x86-64-apple-ios-simulator)

In my project, I have to cleat Cordiva - Firebase relationship.
After,question,I did two Implementation.

STEP1: Find out why I can't build
Refer to the above article or build on the our iPhone.

STEP２: Organize compatibility
Make CORDOVA a parent element and make other targets child elements

THANKS!!